# Evaluation of divergent hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I try to calculate the following hypergeometric function:

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{n+1, n+1, n+3/2}, {2n+3}, -1]
```

for several positive natural values $n=0,1,2,\ldots$,
but Mathematica give as result `Infintity`, which is logical because this hypergeometric function of course diverges for any value, but Maple is capable of giving values. Is it possible to get the same results in Mathematica?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide your Mathematica code. Where did you find Mathematica function  `HyperGeometric3F1`?

Comment: In Mathematica syntax: `HypergeometricPFQ[{n+1, n+1, n+3/2}, {2n+3}, -1]`

Comment: XE   Maple say that $$\, _3F_1\left(1,1,\frac{3}{2};3;-1\right)=0.7391205037880855294637891218743701306027945181746889830708299919761323612223322$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\, _3F_1\left(n+1,n+1,n+\frac{3}{2};2 n+3;-1\right)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((n+1)_k\right){}^2 \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)_k
   (-1)^k}{(2 n+3)_k k!}=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k 2^{1-2 k} (1+n) \Gamma (1+k+n) \Gamma (2+2 k+2 n)}{\Gamma (1+k) \Gamma
   (1+n) \Gamma (3+k+2 n)}=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k 2^{1-2 k} (1+n) \Gamma (1+k+n) \int_0^{\infty } t^{1+2 k+2 n} \exp (-t)
   \, dt}{\Gamma (1+k) \Gamma (1+n) \Gamma (3+k+2 n)}=\\\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k 2^{1-2 k} (1+n)
   \Gamma (1+k+n) t^{1+2 k+2 n}}{\Gamma (1+k) \Gamma (1+n) \Gamma (3+k+2 n)}\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } 2 e^{-t} (1+n) t^{1+2 n}
   \, _1\tilde{F}_1\left(1+n;3+2 n;-\frac{t^2}{4}\right) \, dt=\\\frac{4^{n+1} (n+1) G_{2,3}^{3,1}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,2 n+3 \\
 n+1,n+1,n+\frac{3}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (n+1)}$$

```
f[n_]:= (4^(1 + n) (1 + n) MeijerG[{{1}, {3 + 2 n}}, {{1 + n, 1 + n, 3/2 + n}, {}}, 1])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1 + n])

N[f[0], 100]
(*0.7391205037880855294637891218743701306027945181746889830708299919761323612223322420425589635789669557 + 0.*10^-101 I*)

ListLinePlot[Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 0, 10, 1/5}], PlotRange -> All](*A nice Plot*)
```

In `Maple` you can use `convert` function to convert  Hypergeometric function to MeijerG function:
`convert(hypergeom([n + 1, n + 1, n + 3/2], [2*n + 3], -1), MeijerG)`

then you get:

`4*MeijerG([[1], [2*n + 3]], [[n + 1, n + 1, n + 3/2], []], 1)*(n + 1)*2^(2*n)/(sqrt(Pi)*GAMMA(n + 1))`